# Visual Studio 2019 F# NU1101 Unable to find package FSharp.core

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2019

I'm just starting with  Microsoft Visual Studio and F#.

I have followed their tutorial as close as I can but when I try to run the code they tell me to I get the error:

`NU1101: Unable to find package FSharp.Core. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages`

the entire code I have in the file looks like:

```
module HelloSquare

let square x = x * x

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "%d squared is: %d!" 12 (square 12)
    0 // Return an integer exit code
```

How can i fix this? Any help would be appreciated and I absolutely am willing to provide more info if it will help tackle the problem.

edit:
its a .NET core project

here's the tutorial I'm following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-visual-studio

here is the installation tutorial i followed I did the visual studio section, not the visual studio code, mac, or servers sections:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/install-fsharp#install-f-with-visual-studio

How would I switch to online nuget source?

Comment: Is this a .NET Framework project, or .NET Core? Can you share a link to the tutorial you're using?

Comment: Can you switch to the online Nuget source? Not sure but maybe it is indeed not part of the offline packages (there might be an option in the VS installer for that?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check that you have at least one nuget source configured using:

```
dotnet nuget list source
```

it should return something like:

```
Registered Sources:
  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

If you don't have any sources configured then use [dotnet nuget add source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source) to add one.

e.g.:

```
dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org
```

I think this may be an issue with current version of dotnet core (5.0.6)

Comment: In my installation, it returned:
Registered Sources:
  1.  Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [Enabled]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

So it seems that the nuget source IS configured but a local source is not valid.

I run the add source command as you put and now I have two sources, one local and one remote, and everything works fine.

Thanks!