# F# Can't install nugets because doesn't find default nuget source

Tags: f#, nuget, nuget-package-restore, f#-interactive

I'm trying to install some nuget packages using vs code in F# interactive (fsx script). It has worked before because I have successfully installed FSharp.Data, but it seems to not work (anymore).

Following error

> No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org (vs code)

Code

```
open System.IO
open System
Environment.CurrentDirectory <- __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__


#r "nuget:System.Data.Linq.dll"
#r "nuget:FSharp.Data.SqlClient.dll"
```

A related issue says to list the nuget sources through commandline:
[Visual Studio 2019 F# NU1101 Unable to find package FSharp.core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843634/visual-studio-2019-f-nu1101-unable-to-find-package-fsharp-core)

When I do this I get a correct response:

[image]

So what is going on here?

Comment: As Im concerned, you should not add ".dll" extension at the end of nuget package name.

Answer (score 4):

When You use nuget prefix in the #r directive, you don't have to add ".dll" extension at the end of package name. It is required only when you are referencing local dlls.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tools/fsharp-interactive/